# Create Error Message if table doen't exist pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I've tried some research but found nothing similar to my problem.

I've found Indeed a lot of ways to check if a table exist but I guess my problem it's that my tables has plain text and a variable like `Opened_". $DataDeConsulta ."`

I've tried the following code but I might missing something.. Can anyone help me out please? Thanks in advance!

```
if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("Select 1 from `Opened_". $DataDeConsulta ."`");
    $stmt->execute(["Opened_". $DataDeConsulta .""]);
    $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    if ($count <= 0) {
        $msg="No Data Found";
        echo($msg);
    }
    else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM filecleaner.`Opened_". $DataDeConsulta ."`";
    $_SESSION['DataDeConsulta'] = $DataDeConsulta;
    $query_result=$pdo->query($sql);
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. htmlentities($row['Emails']) . '</td>';
        echo ' ';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    Database::disconnect();
    }
}
```

`$Valid` it's set on another page (just an error validation)

Comment: Apart from the fact that you are not using a placeholder so there is nothing to bind, you cannot bind table names using a prepared statement. Instead you should use a whitelist / validate the table name and inject it directly in the sql like you are actually doing as well. And selecting from a non-existing table will throw an exception so you can either validate / whitelist before the sql or catch that exception.

Comment: Where should I use the placeholder here?

Comment: ... *you cannot bind table names using a prepared statement*

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution that works in case it could be useful for someone:

```
                if (isset($valid)) {
                $pdo = Database::connect();
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables  WHERE table_schema = 'filecleaner'  AND table_name = 'Opened_". $DataDeConsulta ."'");
                $stmt->execute(["Opened_". $DataDeConsulta .""]);
                $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
                if ($count <= 0) {
                    $msg="No Data Found";
                    echo($msg);
                }
                else{
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM filecleaner.`Opened_". $DataDeConsulta ."`";
                $_SESSION['DataDeConsulta'] = $DataDeConsulta;
                $query_result=$pdo->query($sql);
                foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'. htmlentities($row['Emails']) . '</td>';
                    echo ' ';
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                Database::disconnect();
                }
            }
```